# JavaScript array displays "first" and "second" number

Tags: javascript

Using an array, How can I prompt to enter 2 numbers and display:                              "First number entered is: x"
"Second number entered is: y"

Comment: `var arr = []; arr[0] = prompt("First number"); arr[1] = prompt("Second number"); alert("First number entered is: " + arr[0] + ", second number entered is: " + arr[1]);`

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what issues and errors are you running into? We're usually glad to help, but you have to show that you've at least tried it first.

Comment: it's too basic "displaying" problem

Answer (score 2):

here it is:

```
var a = ["23","67"];
alert("first number is "+a[0]+" \n second number is "+a[1]);
```